# Getting faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper When Executing WS Client

Tags: web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I needed some help fixing this issue that i am facing currently with WS class. When i execute the client i get this exception. I googled for a solution, but done seem to find anything that would help.

The exception that i see is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: The following WSDL exception occurred: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:9090/TimeServiceWS/services/TimeServerImplService  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1202)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:249)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:172)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:134)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:218)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:83)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:79)  
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)  
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:707)  
    at ch01.ts.TimeServerConsumer.main(TimeServerConsumer.java:47)  
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:9090/TimeServiceWS/services/TimeServerImplService  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:234)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.<init>(WSDL4JWrapper.java:156)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1182)  
    ... 11 more  
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:9090/TimeServiceWS/services/TimeServerImplService  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:203)  
    ... 13 more  
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:9090/TimeServiceWS/services/TimeServerImplService  
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$14.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:974)  
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.getInputStream(WSDL4JWrapper.java:971)  
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:189)  
    ... 13 more
```

I have deployed my WS in Tomcat. If you need the code and the WSDL, let me know, I would provide it. I asked this on some other forums as well without any help. So some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This one in particular looks like your path

```
http://localhost:9090/TimeServiceWS/services/TimeServerImplService
```

is having some sort of internal error. I would look at your logs but without any other code it is impossible to tell.